# C# - when do I need override? When don't I need it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using C# with Unity3d.

When I use Monobehaviour and create an Update method, I don't need to use the override keyword.

When I create my own class and override a function, I do need to use the override keyword.

Why is that?  Why do I not need the override keyword when creating the Update method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that Unity does something special about these methods (`Update`, `Start`, `Awake`, etc). You can declare them as private and even then they will be called. That's not achievable using the language unless you use *reflection*, but I was told they don't use it, so I don't know what they do. And honestly, it doesn't matter. Because you can think as this being an exception to the language, that is, these methods will be called if you implement them. Simply that.

For all the rest, you have to follow the language. Here is a rough explanation:

You can or have to `override` a method if it is marked as `abstract` or `virtual` in the base class.

A method is `abstract` when the base class wants its children to implement it. A method is `virtual` when the base class offers an implementation of it but also offers an opportunity for the children to implement/modify that method.

So why can't all methods be "overridable"? To protect the base class developer's intention. You'd be changing the behaviour of a base class, you don't know if the base class developer would like you to do this. It's like a security lock. So that's why you have the three words `abstract`, `virtual` and `override`, to communicate the API intentions from the base class to their children.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `override`, when you derive a class from another class and you need to change the code of a method of the base class that is `virtual`. This way the inheritted method of the base class can have a different behaviour -more suitable- for the derived class.

More generally, as it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx):

> The override modifier is *required* to **extend or modify** the abstract or virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event.

Comment: How do I create a situation where I don't have to use the word override?

Comment: This depends on what you have to do. What I mean is the following: Let you define a base class with some methods and then define some derived classes based on this base class. If you none of the methods of your base class shouldn't be overriden, then none of them should be marked as virtual. Last but not least in the derived class you will not have the ability to override this methods.

Comment: On the other hand, if you select to derive a class from a base class, which has one (or more methods), whose code doesn't reflect that you want to do with them, then if these methos are not virtual, you have to mark them as virtual and then override them in the derived classes.